# fetching Cloud Data Fusion Runtime info

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I want to pass the runid of Data fusion pipeline to some function upon pipeline completion but i am not able to find any run-time variable which holds this value. Please help!

Comment: Hello! I would like to clarify if you want to retrieve the run_id during pipeline run or after completion? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ines,

I want to pass the run_id of the pipeline to a cloud fucntion when pipeline succeeds via HTTP Pipeline alert. I dont know if there is any variable, argument that holds the run_id of the pipeline which i can refer to pass to the function.

Comment: Hi Sudhir, currently there is runtime information that has the runId information. Can I ask what is it you are trying to do in the cloud function that requires the pipeline runId? We have this JIRA for the feature request: https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-12719

Comment: Hi Edwin,

I am planning do fetch the pipeline stats like Records.in , out of Plugins using the 'POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/metrics/query"' API which requires RuniD of a Pipeline run as input in the body.
So when Pipeline succeeds I want to pass its RunID to a Cloud Function and Cloud Function will fetch the stats with that runid.
Refer: https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference#metrics_for_a_batch_pipeline

Comment: Hi Edwin,

You mentioned that this information is there in runtime information. I tried accessing runtime['runid'] and runtime['run_id'] but this two doesn't exist. What is the key in runtime to get the run_id ?

Answer (score 1):

As an update to the previous answer, the first thing to do is to obtain the details of the deployed pipelines in a given namespace. For this, the following endpoint should be queried: `'/v3/namespaces/${NAMESPACE}/apps'`. Where `${NAMESPACE}` is the namespace where the pipeline is deployed.

This endpoint returns a list with the pipelines deployed on this namespace `${NAMESPACE}` (not the pipeline JSON, just a high level description list). Once the pipeline list is obtained, to obtain the run metrics of a given pipeline, the following endpoint should be called: `'/v3/namespaces/${NAMESPACE}/apps/${PIPELINE}/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/runs'`, where `${PIPELINE}` is the name of the pipeline. This endpoint will return the details of all the runs for this pipeline. This is where the run_id can be obtained. The field containing the run_id is actually called `runid` in this list.

With the run_id, you can then obtain all the run logs for example by querying the endpoint `'{CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/{NAMESPACE}/apps/{PIPELINE}/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/runs/{run["runid"]}/logs?start={run["start"]}&stop={run["start"]}'`. The previous snippet is a python snippet where `run` is a dictionary containing the run details of a particular run.

As explained in the CDAP [microservice guide](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477593807/CDAP+Microservices+Guide), to call these endpoints, the CDAP endpoint must be obtained by running the command: `gcloud beta data-fusion instances describe --project=${PROJECT} --location=${REGION} --format="value(apiEndpoint)" ${INSTANCE_ID}`. The authentication token will also be needed and this can be found through running: `gcloud auth print-access-token`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer has been provided by @Edwin Elia in the comment section:

Retrieving the `run-id` of a Data Fusion pipeline within its run or the predecessor pipeline's is not possible currently. Here is an [enhancement](https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-12719) that you can track that would make it possible.

When talking about retrieving the `run_id` value after pipeline completion you should be able to use the REST API from the CDAP [documentation](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/477560983/Lifecycle+HTTP+RESTful+API#Retrieving-Specific-Run-Information) to get information on the run including the run-id.